# sql trigger - update/insert

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, database-trigger

one thing I´m struggling with is the definition of triggers in SQL. I need to implement a code for a given table such that:
-for any new row inserted in the table, the trigger is activated and the table stores current date on the attribute date. the issue I have with the code included below is that updates all rows in the table, and onle want the inserted table to be updated with the current date.

```
CREATE FUNCTION func()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
value DATE;
BEGIN
SELECT CURRENT_DATE INTO fecha;
UPDATE tabla SET date = value;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER date
AFTER INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE func();
```

for any update on any row of the table, the trigger is activated and again, stores the current date on the attribute date.

```
CREATE FUNCTION func2()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
value DATE;
BEGIN
SELECT CURRENT_DATE INTO value;
SET NEW.date=value;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER date
AFTER UPDATE ON table 
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE func2();
```

Comment: Which database? Some of this will depend on whether it sql server, postgres, etc. Please add a tag. I have no idea what a tag "rows" means, whoever added that, it seems useless to me!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response. Database is postgress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `BEFORE` trigger instead that manipulates the row that is getting inserted/updated:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW.date = CURRENT_DATE ;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER date
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE func();
```

Comment: You could simplify this into one trigger by using `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE`.